# trigger select box event using option text not option value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// In jquery
$('.check').val('two').trigger('change');
// and html is 
<select class="check">
<option value="one">First</option>
<option value="two">Second</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7QWd/353/
I need trigger the event using my text value i.e. "First" in jquery. Any solution of it? Here I have used .val('two')  instead I wish to use "First"..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to select the option by its text, if so you can use [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) - but it can give expected matches since it will use partial matches

So try

```js
$(function() {
  $('.check').change(function() {
    var data = $(this).val();
    snippet.log('data:' + data)
      //if you want the selected text
    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    snippet.log('text:' + text)
  });

  $('.check option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Second'
  }).prop('selected', true)
  $('.check').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="check">
  <option value="one">First</option>
  <option value="two">Second</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()` to get the selected option text and `.change()` to trigger initially on load

```
$('.check').change(function(){
  var data= $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  if(data == 'First'){
      // your logic
   }            
}).change();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v7QWd/354/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.check option:selected').text() == "First") {
        $('.check').trigger('change');
    }
```

```js
$(function () {

    //change to two ? how?

    $('.check').change(function () {
        var data = $(this).val();
        alert(data);
    });
    if ($('.check option:selected').text() == "First") {
        $('.check').trigger('change');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="check">
    <option value="one">First</option>
    <option value="two">Second</option>
</select>
```